# Class not found exception Android

Tags: android, class

I've got strange problem with Eclipse. After I've updated my app from svn the app crashes and I'm getting that error:

```
06-29 09:32:55.120: E/AndroidRuntime(13224): java.lang.RuntimeException: 
Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{de.re.ab/de.re.ab.FerieActivity}:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: de.re.ab.FerieActivity
```

Looks like he's searching for the class in subfolder(?). Please tell me how to fix this;)

Comment: make sure you are registering FerieActivity in manifast as:

Comment: Clean the project and run again.

Comment: Have you added this class to the Manifest file?

Comment: It's the only activity in the app, so yes,it is in manifest.

Project was cleaned, no effect.

Comment: then check your package name `de.re.ab` or any other

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="de.re.ab"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
<application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

Comment: <activity
            android:name=".FerieActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
    </application>

</manifest>

Comment: @user1341280 : try as android:name=".ab.FerieActivity" instead of ndroid:name=".FerieActivity"

Comment: @user1341280 : make sure FerieActivity class is not abstract? or past code of FerieActivity class

Comment: @user1341280 can tell the first line of your FerieActivity class like package de.r...... ..... ?

Answer (score 0):

is it possible, that someone has renamed the package? what's the name of the package in your project's `gen` folder?

have you tried to run "Android Tools" -> "Fix Project Properties..." ?

Answer (score 0):

Try closing and reopening eclipse. I did this and it solved the problem.